# Pure CSS dropdown menu issue

Tags: html, menu, dropdown

simply and shortly, trying to learn code above, but got lost. i.e listing 4 links (or w/e to call them) to your menu works just fine with responsive drop down, but if I do more, 5-6 etc, they are not appearing in drop down menu, what's wrong?

```css
/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="/" class="logo">AGT</a>
  
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
    <span class="navicon"></span> 
  </label>
  
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fifth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

There's fiddle to make it easier: https://jsfiddle.net/ug6f918s/1012/

Comment: Line 93 of your Fiddle CSS. `.menu` has a max-height of 240px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change or edit this class:

```
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}
```

Right now it prevents your dropdown menu of exceeding 240 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

delete the  max-height:0;

```
/* menu */

.header .menu {
clear: both;
*max-height: 0;*
transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: apparently if you change this line, it 'll auto drop down without clicking the button. 
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

had problem in it, thanks to the answers above (: